# Convert timestamp coming from SQL database to String

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

I am saving the timestamp in SQL as bigint(20). The number is correct and in android or https://www.epochconverter.com it works fine.

However I am not able to create a date-string based on the timestamp received from database.

First of all, the timestamp seems to come from database as a String, so I can't just say `echo date("d.m.Y, $timestamp)`. The result is the famous 31.12.1969.

So I tried `echo date("d.m.Y, strtotime($timestamp))`. However, even though strtotime is said to be able to convert almost everything to a timestamp, a simple String containing a timestamp is not possible. Results still remained on the last day of Brian Adams probably favorite year.

Some progress I made by casting the $timestamp to a float value like so: `echo date("d.m.Y", floatval($timestamp));`. However, now things got really confusing for me. I seemed to have successfully converted my timestamp, however, `date()` gave me the dates around 02.09.52299.

The timestamps I am using are timestamps of current time, e.g. 1588489252657, which currently leads to the date 23.03.52307.

So all I want is to come to a date based on the timestamp 1588489252657 to see the 03.05.2020 on my screen.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Convert that timestamp from milliseconds to seconds and you will get the right date

Comment: From your own conversor: *Assuming that this timestamp is in milliseconds*

Comment: Thanks for the two answers. The main point for me was that I had to transform the timestamp from milliseconds to seconds. After this using ```echo date("d.m.Y", floatval($timestamp) / 1000);``` worked fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```php
<?php

$timestamp = 1588489252657; // Timestamp in Milliseconds
$seconds = round($timestamp/1000, 0); // Timestamp Rounded to Seconds

$date = new DateTime();  // Create PHP DateTime Object
$date->setTimestamp($seconds); // Set the Timestamp
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // Specify the Required Format
```

The answers are pretty much in the comment sections. But I have shared this answer since this is another approach in OOP fashion. You can leverage the power of PHP's DateTime Class.

PHP Official Documentation For DateTime Class Link Below:
[PHP DateTime Class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: Thanks for the two answers. The main point for me was that I had to transform the timestamp from milliseconds to seconds. After this using ```echo date("d.m.Y", floatval($timestamp) / 1000);``` worked fine

Answer (score 2):

You have to transform the timestamp to seconds first.

```php
$timestamp = 1588489252657;
$dateInUnixSeconds = round($timestamp / 1000, 0);
$date = \DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('U', (string) $dateInUnixSeconds);

echo $date->format('d.m.Y');
```

PS: 
I recommend you to use the `\DateTimeImmutable` object to avoid mutability problems.
https://github.com/Chemaclass/php-best-practices/blob/master/technical-skills/immutability.md

Comment: Thanks for the two answers. The main point for me was that I had to transform the timestamp from milliseconds to seconds. After this using ```echo date("d.m.Y", floatval($timestamp) / 1000);``` worked fine.